# How to crop face detection result using gcloud command line

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-vision

I have uploaded an image in my Google Cloud Storage inside a bucket. Then I open the gcloud command line and I run the following:

```
gcloud ml vision detect-faces gs://my-bucket/face.png
```

I can see the result in json format, so I understand that it returns the position of the face and some face features.

How can I save/export a cropped image containing just the face, using the gcloud command line?

In other words, in the below example, how can I export as a separate image the area within the larger green box?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using face detection API, you get back a rectangle that identifies the found face.  If what you now want is to create a new image (which could replace the old image if desired) containing just the face, you can use a tool like [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php).  This can be command line executed.  This tool takes as input a source image, commands and generates a new image.  One of the commands is [-crop](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#crop) which will crop an image given an input rectangle (the face box).